# Probability of all samples are distinct in continuous random variable

Tags: probability

I want to compute the probability of $n$ iid samples $X_{i \in [n]}$ are all distinct when the population is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

I can easily compute this quantity if the population is discrete, but it's hard for me to imagine how to write this down in a closed form in continuous case.

Comment: $$\mathsf P(X_1=X_2) = \int_{A} \text{2D standard Gaussian density}(x,y) \,\mathrm d(x,y)=0,$$ since $A\overset{\text{Def.}}=\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb R\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a null set for the 2 dimensional Lebesgue measure. Repeat this argument to see that the probability that any two of the r.v.s are equal is $0$, and conclude that the probability that they are all distinct is $1$.